# How should I display search results with scope?

Tags: iphone, ios, search, scope, uisearchbar

I have two scopes in my search bar: City and Church. Every time I perform my search, both scopes displays blank cells, while they do have search results. How do I show their corresponding cell name? Thank you!

I have figured the problem is in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    if ([searchBar.scopeButtonTitles isEqual: @"City"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredResult objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Places"];
    }

    else if ([searchBar.scopeButtonTitles isEqual: @"Church"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredResult objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Church"];
    }
}

else {
    ...
}

[cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
return cell;
```

This is my search:

```
- (void)filterListForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    [filteredResult removeAllObjects];

    if ([scope isEqualToString: @"City"]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dictionarySearch in allRegion) {
            for (NSDictionary *citySearch in [dictionarySearch objectForKey: @"Cities"]) {
                [citySearch objectForKey: @"Cities"];
                NSRange rangeSearch = [[citySearch valueForKey: @"Places"] rangeOfString: searchText options: (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
                if (rangeSearch.location != NSNotFound) {
                    [filteredResult addObject: citySearch];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ([scope isEqualToString: @"Church"]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dictionarySearch in allRegion) {
            for (NSDictionary *citySearch in [dictionarySearch objectForKey: @"Cities"]) {
                for (NSDictionary *churchSearch in [citySearch objectForKey: @"Churches"]) {
                    [churchSearch objectForKey: @"Churches"];
                    NSRange rangeSearch = [[churchSearch valueForKey: @"Church"] rangeOfString: searchText options: (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
                    if (rangeSearch.location != NSNotFound) {
                        [filteredResult addObject: churchSearch];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        if (searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredResult objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Places"];
        }

        else if (searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 1) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredResult objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Church"];
        }
    }

    else {
        ...
    }

    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;
}
```

`searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 0` for scope City and `searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 1` for scope Church

Answer (score 0):

Hope [This Example](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/) will help you out.
just place your "if" and "else if" things in "filterContentForSearchText" for "searchResults" in the linked example, that will surely work.

Comment: As you can see, your filterContentForSearchText is the same as my filterListForSearchText. The only difference is you are using NSPredicate while I didn't. I still don't get the point. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think using NSMutableArray with searchbar will help you. You can get the sample project from the link .https://github.com/AalokParikh/MyDemoApps